# how can I flatten a list of arguments?

Tags: python

Say I have a variable-length function like:

```
def foo(*args):
  for x in args:
    print(x)
```

Given a list like `[1,2]`, how can I call `foo` such that 1 and 2 are passed as two separate arguments to `foo`, rather than a single list argument to it? I.e., I want to call foo as `foo(1,2)` rather than `foo([1,2])

Comment: Like `foo(*some_list)`?

Comment: Actually you can pass as separate arguments. `foo(1, 2)` works. Did you try?